# Trouble returning a string from Alert

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a todo-list app and I am having a lot of trouble returning the text input from an Alert.

This is in a separate file ex: 'AddItem.swift'

```
func showAddItemDialog(view: UIViewController) -> String {
    var textOfTask = UITextField()
    var textValue = ""

    let diag = UIAlertController(title: "Add Task", message: "Enter a task name", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    diag.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in })
    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        textOfTask = diag.textFields![0] as UITextField
        textValue = textOfTask.text!

        addListItem(textValue)
    }))

    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in }))
    view.presentViewController(diag, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("returning " + textValue)
    return textValue
}
```

And I am trying to have the text value ('textValue') of the Alert's text box be returned to the caller.

I have tried a bunch of ways but have not come up with anything and what I have above returns nothing because the function does not stop and wait for the alert to show before returning. I want to avoid putting this code into the ViewController file as I have read that it's bad practice, but I really can't figure this out.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know! Thanks!

Edit:

I am calling this function with:

```
@IBAction func didPressAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
    showAddItemDialog(self)
}
```

Comment: *This* method returns right after you present the view controller.  Thats before the actions you create have been tapped.  You'll have to find another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What does addListItem(textValue) do?

Comment: @nhgrif yeah that's my issue. I can't seem to figure out another way to do it.

Comment: @ryantxr that saves the textbox text to Firebase

Comment: Can you post how you are calling this function.

Comment: @ryantxr Sure. 
`    @IBAction func didPressAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
        showAddItemDialog(self)
    }
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the code won't wait for the person to enter data and click the OK button. The answer is to use a completion handler.

```
// This is a slightly modified version of your code
func showAddItemDialog(view: UIViewController, completion: (text: String?) -> Void ) {

    var textOfTask = UITextField()
    var textValue = ""

    let diag = UIAlertController(title: "Add Task", message: "Enter a task name", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    diag.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in })
    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        textOfTask = diag.textFields![0] as UITextField
        textValue = textOfTask.text!

        addListItem(textValue)
        completion(text: textValue)
    }))

    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        completion(text: nil)
    }))
    view.presentViewController(diag, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// In the view controller
@IBAction func didPressAdd(sender: AnyObject) { 

    // Call it like this:
    showAddItemDialog(self) {
        (text) in
        // handle the result value here
        if let textUserEntered = text {
            // User entered some text and pressed OK
        }
        else {
            // User pressed cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I'm still new to swift and what it can do / how to do things, but I am learning a ton. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As @nhgrif says in his comment, you can't return a value as the result of your function. The function returns as soon as it hands the alert to the system for display, and before the alert is even drawn to the screen.

This is a very common beginner mistake when dealing with async methods.

You need to refactor your `showAddItemDialog` function to take a completion closure with a string parameter. In the closure for your add action, fetch the text from the field of the alert and then invoke the closure that's passed to you, giving it the string.

Then when you call your `showAddItemDialog` function, pass it a closure that does whatever you need to do with the text you collect from the user.

Comment: Yeah I see now. Still new to swift but these are great learning experiences. Thanks!